# dotNetOpenAuth how to debug a protocol exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, protocolexception

I've been trying to debug a dotnetOpenAuth.Messaging.Protocol exception for awhile and I can't figure out how to find the exact problem and fix it.

I've been using MVC and I am trying to log a user with Oauth2. It works just fine for the normal login in flow, but when a user resets their password and then automatically gets redirected to the controller for the oauth login I get the following error:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Unexpected OAuth authorization response received with callback
        and client state that does not match an expected value.
Source=DotNetOpenAuth.Core
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem or how to figure out what is wrong with my request any sort of direction would be much appreciated.

It is this line specifically that is causing me problems:

```
 OAuthClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(Request);
```

But I'm not sure what is wrong with my request or how to go about checking.